# Android react-native-webview “SSL Error: Hostname mismatch” (expo)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-webview

when I use the WebView on expo with an external uri which I’m not the owner (I’m doing an SSO Auth page that uses cookies), if I open on iOS everything works fine, but if I try on Android it gives me error code 2 "SSL ERROR: Hostname Mismatch" and I can’t open the webpage. I don’t know how to solve this in a good way, I’m using react-native-webview with expo sdk 39 (not bare workflow, but totally with expo). Even if i edit the node_modules files in react-native-webview-removing the handleOnSslError check in Android folder it seems to not detect the changes.

[Here the console error showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Oca.png)

I hope hearing from you as soon as possible for a solution or a workaround, I'm really in trouble with this problem for weeks!

Comment: were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: there is no elegant way to figure it out, the only way to solve this problem is to eject in a react native application and remove the SSL error check in android folder of react-native-webview

Answer (score 0):

What I did that I tried with nonsecured URL for example:-
https://google.com
try replacing it with http://google.com
and it worked for me.